# Android WiFi Мультиплеер

Tags: java, android, сокет, wifi

Решил добавить в одно из своих приложений возможность игры по локальной WiFi сети.
Сразу пошёл гуглить клиент/сервер на сокетах. Одно устройство, которое сервер, раздает Wifi, а второе подключается к этой сети. Но проблема в том, что сервер не видит то, что отправляет ему клиент. Если в одном устройстве запустить и сервер и клиент, то все работает. Как сделать сервер видимым в данной сети? Как клиенту найти IP сервера и подключиться к нему?
Вот код:

Server.java:

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {
    MainActivity activity;
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;

    Handler updateConversationHandler;

    Thread serverThread = null;

    private TextView text;


    public static final int SERVERPORT = 5000;

    public Server(MainActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.text = activity.msg;
    }

    public void start() {
        updateConversationHandler = new Handler();

        this.serverThread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
        this.serverThread.start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        try {
            if (!serverSocket.isClosed())
                serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class ServerThread implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            Socket socket = null;
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                try {

                    socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    final String adress = socket.toString();
                    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(activity, adress, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                    CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(socket);
                    new Thread(commThread).start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class CommunicationThread implements Runnable {

        private Socket clientSocket;

        private BufferedReader input;

        public CommunicationThread(Socket clientSocket) {

            this.clientSocket = clientSocket;

            try {

                this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void run() {


            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                try {

                    String read = input.readLine();

                    updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread(read));

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    class updateUIThread implements Runnable {
        private String msg;

        public updateUIThread(String str) {
            this.msg = str;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            text.setText(text.getText().toString() + "Client Says: " + msg + "\n");
        }

    }

}
```

Client.java :

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Client {

    private Socket socket;
    private MainActivity activity;
    private static final int SERVERPORT = 5000;
    private static final String SERVER_IP = "10.0.2.2";

    public Client(MainActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public void start() {
        new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
    }

    public void onClick() {
        try {
            String str = activity.edit.getText().toString();
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                    true);
            out.println(str);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class ClientThread implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

    public void stop() {
        if (!socket.isClosed()) {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Я нашёл решение свей проблемы [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/208132/).

Данный вопрос можно решить используя библиотеку [JmDNS](http://jmdns.sourceforge.net/)

Например так

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;

import javax.jmdns.JmDNS;
import javax.jmdns.ServiceEvent;
import javax.jmdns.ServiceInfo;
import javax.jmdns.ServiceListener;

/**
 * @author alwx
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class NetworkDiscovery {
  private final String DEBUG_TAG = NetworkDiscovery.class.getName();
  private final String TYPE = "_alwx._tcp.local.";
  private final String SERVICE_NAME = "LocalCommunication";

  private Context mContext;
  private JmDNS mJmDNS;
  private ServiceInfo mServiceInfo;
  private ServiceListener mServiceListener;
  private WifiManager.MulticastLock mMulticastLock;

  public NetworkDiscovery(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    try {
      WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) mContext.getSystemService(android.content.Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
      WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
      int intaddr = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();

      byte[] byteaddr = new byte[]{
          (byte) (intaddr & 0xff),
          (byte) (intaddr >> 8 & 0xff),
          (byte) (intaddr >> 16 & 0xff),
          (byte) (intaddr >> 24 & 0xff)
      };
      InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByAddress(byteaddr);
      mJmDNS = JmDNS.create(addr);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Error in JmDNS creation: " + e);
    }
  }

  /**
   * starts server with defined names on given port
   *
   * @param port server port
   */
  public void startServer(int port) {
    try {
      wifiLock();
      mServiceInfo = ServiceInfo.create(TYPE, SERVICE_NAME, port, SERVICE_NAME);
      mJmDNS.registerService(mServiceInfo);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Error in JmDNS initialization: " + e);
    }
  }

  /**
   * performs servers discovery
   *
   * @param listener listener, that will be called after successful discovery
   *                 (see {@link me.alwx.localcommunication.connection.NetworkDiscovery.OnFoundListener}
   */
  public void findServers(final OnFoundListener listener) {
    mJmDNS.addServiceListener(TYPE, mServiceListener = new ServiceListener() {
      @Override
      public void serviceAdded(ServiceEvent serviceEvent) {
        ServiceInfo info = mJmDNS.getServiceInfo(serviceEvent.getType(), serviceEvent.getName());
        listener.onFound(info);
      }

      @Override
      public void serviceRemoved(ServiceEvent serviceEvent) {
      }

      @Override
      public void serviceResolved(ServiceEvent serviceEvent) {
        mJmDNS.requestServiceInfo(serviceEvent.getType(), serviceEvent.getName(), 1);
      }
    });
  }

  /**
   * closes connection & unregisters all services
   */
  public void reset() {
    if (mJmDNS != null) {
      if (mServiceListener != null) {
        mJmDNS.removeServiceListener(TYPE, mServiceListener);
        mServiceListener = null;
      }
      mJmDNS.unregisterAllServices();
    }
    if (mMulticastLock != null && mMulticastLock.isHeld()) {
      mMulticastLock.release();
    }
  }

  /**
   * accuires Wi-Fi lock
   */
  private void wifiLock() {
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) mContext.getSystemService(android.content.Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    mMulticastLock = wifiManager.createMulticastLock(SERVICE_NAME);
    mMulticastLock.setReferenceCounted(true);
    mMulticastLock.acquire();
  }

  public interface OnFoundListener {
    void onFound(ServiceInfo info);
  }
}
```